# vis.js network - how to create square with a picture inside?

Tags: image, padding, shapes, vis.js, vis.js-network

I want to make a network node with a shape "square", load the picture inside and have a padding around it to see the shape background colour. background colour would indicate an alarm state of the node. 
Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried the `margin` property of a node?

Comment: @YakovL recently I contributed to visjs-network https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/pull/106. I added `imagePadding` property for network and node options. This allows me just use an `Image` shape and set padding around the image.

Answer (score 1):

The silution is to use vis.js event beforeDrawing to draw the background square on the canvas.